# HTML Table gap between Row (IE only, Chrome OK)

Tags: html, internet-explorer, html-table

I have a image tag (as below) in my table, when view in IE there is a gap between the rows but not happening in Chrome.

[image: Gap between the first and second row]

My HTML code is as below

```
<table id="Table_01" width="1282" border="0" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0">
        <tr>
            <td colspan="3">
                <img id="login_01" src="/image/login_01.png?v=1" width="1282" height="156" alt="" usemap="#mapLogo" border="0" />
            </td>
        </tr>
```

Answer (score 0):

Upon testing, it seems like the gap was due to my code structure. By changing my Row tag as below, where the TD and IMG and /TD under single line, IE is showing properly.

```
<table id="Table_01" width="1282" border="0" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0">
        <tr>
            <td colspan="3"><img id="login_01" src="/image/login_01.png?v=1" width="1282" height="156" alt="" usemap="#mapLogo" border="0" /></td>
        </tr>
```

[image: Immediate the gap is gone!]

No more gap in IE and Chrome.. Nice job Microsoft!

Comment: That should not make a bit of difference.   You might be having issues with caching preventing changes you make showing up immediately.